# Akka .Net actor separation

Tags: c#, .net, akka.net

I'm new with Akka.Net and I want to create 10 actors that will process my messages based on the ID of the message, i.e. ActorA will only process messages with ID ending with 0, ActorB messages with ID ending with 1 etc. In my case, ID is just string property called EmployeeNumber. Below is what I've done.
Message class:

```
public class Message : IConsistentHashable
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public object ConsistentHashKey => EmployeeNumber.Last().ToString();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{EmployeeNumber} : {MessageText}";
    }
}
```

Actor class:

```
 public class ProcessingActor : UntypedActor
{
    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {            
        var output = message as Message;
        if (output == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"I'm actor {Context.Self.Path}, I received message: {message}");
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
tatic void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.Create("system"))
        {
            Props processingActorProps = Props.Create<ProcessingActor>().WithRouter(new ConsistentHashingPool(10));
            IActorRef processingActor = system.ActorOf(processingActorProps, "ProcessingActorsPool");

            var messages = GetSomeMessages();
            foreach (Message message in messages)
            {
                processingActor.Tell(message);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

GetSomeMessages() method is just returning list with 10 hardcoded messages. The problem is my solution isn't working, I expect that separate 10 actors will be 
processing my messages, but I can see that i.e. message with EmployeeNumber 12345 and 12340 are processed by the same actor. I would love to someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as [the docs for `Routers`](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html#consistenthashing) read,

> The idea is that messages with the same key are forwarded to the same routee.

So in your code example it is guaranteed that all messages that have the `EmployeeNumber` ending with the same character will be processed by the same `Actor`, but there are no guarantees on them being distributed evenly between the `Actors`.

If you really want every message be processed by the appropriate `Actor` efficiently, you could just extend the abstract `RoutingLogic` class and override the `Routee Select(object message, Routee[] routees)` method to pair digits with their `Actors`.